# Apple Maps Licence for use in app

Tags: maps, google-maps

Do Apple Maps have any limitations or any licence fees, if I use them in an app that I develop?

For eg: google maps are free for 2500 uses per day in applications:
https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing

Is there any such Information on Apple Maps or are they just free for iPad and iPhone apps?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are no license fees - nor limitations such as the "fleet management" exception with the old Google Maps based API.

You need to check your individual license terms with Apple. They're provided for you in the Developer Center under Contracts.

Comment: Okay I searched trough the Web for hours and missed the Developer Center :) Thx